# Let $V$ subspace of $W$, with $\dim V=\dim W$. Why should they be equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The fact that $V$ is a subspace of $W$ , means $\dim V \leq \dim W$ . We are told $\dim V = \dim W.$ So if $B_1$ is the basis of $V$ and $B_2$ is the basis of $W,$ it is $ |B_1|= |B_2| .$
We know that $B_1$ is a linearly independent set of $V$. The $B_1$ can be extended to a basis $B_2$ of $W$. But we are told that $|B_1|= |B_2|.$ So both $V$ and $W$ are having the same basis. So an element of both is a linear combination of the elements of the basis. So they are equal.

Do you agree?

Comment: The result in the header of your question is true **if** the common dimension is finite, otherwise it is false.

Comment: Just a (small but important) note on grammar: Writing "the" basis suggests (incorrectly) that a vector space has a unique basis. The indefinite article "a" is appropriate, instead, i.e., "If $B_{1}$ is a basis of $V$ and $B_{2}$ is a basis of $W$, then $|B_{1}| = |B_{2}|$."

Comment: There is an answer to this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871081/two-vector-spaces-with-same-dimension-and-same-basis-are-identical

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, this is only true in the case where the dimension is finite. A counter-example in infinite dimensions is simply the set of natural numbers, N, and the set of integer numbers Z. They both have the same dimension, but the former is included in the latter.

Back to your question, we will proceed by *reductio ad absurdum*:

- Suppose there exists $x \in W$, $x \notin V$
- Given a base $B$ of $V$, we know that $x$ is linearly independent of $B$.
- Thus the span of $\{B, x\}$ is an $dim(V)+1$ dimensional space.
- As every element of $B$ is in $V$, the span of $\{B, x\}$ is included in W.
- Thus W is at least of dimension $dim(V)+1$, but our assumption states that $dim(V) = dim(W)$
- Hence, V = W

QED