# For which values of the parameter p does it hold that the vectors are independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ u, v$  and $ w$  be linearly independent vectors in $ \mathbb{R^n} $
. For which values
of the parameter p does it hold that the vectors $ a = u − v, b = u + w, c = u + v − w$
and $ d = p · u + v + w $ are linearly independent as well?

What is the easy way to solve this kind of problem? Can we say 4 vectors in $ \mathbb{R^3}$  are always dependent?

Comment: Tip: Use $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the real numbers. Code is ```\mathbb{R}```.

Comment: thank you edited! what about my question?

Comment: Yes, 4 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are always linearly dependent. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171064/prove-that-if-a-vector-space-has-dimension-n-then-any-n-1-of-its-vectors-are-l)

Comment: what about if we have 3 vectors but question is same.How can I figure it out?

Comment: Which three vectors out of a,b,c, and d?

Comment: For example a b and d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just to restate:
$$\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}$$
$$\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{w}$$
$$\mathbf{d}=p \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}$$
Given $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
They are linearly dependent if $\exists k_1,k_2,k_3 \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ such that
$$k_1 \mathbf{a} + k_2 \mathbf{b} + k_3 \mathbf{d}=0$$
Or
$$k_1(\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v})+k_2(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{w})+k_3(p \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w})=0$$
$$(k_1+k_2+pk_3)\mathbf{u}+(-k_1+k_3)\mathbf{v}+(k_2+k_3)\mathbf{w}=0$$
Since we know that $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent, this can only be true if
$$\begin{bmatrix}
k_{1} +k_{2} +pk_{3}\\
-k_{1} +k_{3}\\
k_{2} +k_{3}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus we want to know if there are any non trivial solutions to the matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & p\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
k_{1}\\
k_{2}\\
k_{3}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
As if there *are* non trivial solutions, it means we have found $k_1, k_2, k_3 \neq 0$ such that $k_1 \mathbf{a} + k_2 \mathbf{b} + k_3 \mathbf{d} = 0$. Therefore, as long as the determinant of the above matrix is nonzero (i.e, we can invert the matrix, multiply both sides by the inverse), $k_1 =k_2=k_3=0$ is the only solution. It can be easily verified that
$$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & p\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right) =-p$$
Therefore $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{d}$ are only linearly independent if $p \neq 0$.

Comment: @subhanceo Sorry for the late reply. Please ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: Thank you for explanation. One thing is unclear I learnt that if determinant is 0 then the vectors are dependent but in this case you say they are independent.

Comment: @subhanceo You are correct! Goodness, what was I thinking? I'll correct it.

Comment: Now everything is clear!